# Automating the Title Column in SharePoint 2007

Tags: list

I am working on editing a list on SharePoint 2007. I want to make the title column automatically generate a new sequential number each time a new task is to be performed. How do I automate the title column or any column to give an incremental number whenever a new task is to be filled in or performed?

for example: First task:  Title= 1909
             Second task: Title= 1910
             Third task:  Title= 1911

Answer (score 0):

User a workflow and two lists.

Your second list will contain nothing but your ID attribute. Your workflow would run on your primary list and access the value in the numbering list and assign it to your title field.  Then before the workflow completes update the sequence in the numbering list so the next item get's the incremental number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But, I am new to SharePoint. I came across this issue while working on improving the business process of a department in a company. Please can you send me instructions on what to do or can you provide me with a link that has the instructions/guidelines?